# Spring Security not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: spring, spring-security

as the title implies I experience slight problems with a simple Spring Security Test. This is my project structure (maven webapp 2.5):

```
main
 java
   de
     cochu
       spring
         controller
           HomeController
webapp
  WEB-INF
    jsp
      home.jsp
      index.jsp
    security-context.xml
    spring-servlet.xml
    web.xml
```

The web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.cochu.spring.controller"/>

<bean id="internalViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

security-context.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/" )
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String show() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/secure", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String secure() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

The exact problem: No login form or whatsoever is opening. It just displays the page. I tried almost every url-pattern combination/intercept-url combination, but no reaction. What is wrong?

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FilterChainProxy` bean is registered with the alias `springSecurityFilterChain` so try modifying your web.xml and change this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

to this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

That's the config I usually use (using spring security 3.1.0.RELEASE)

Comment: I'm really surprised that the name have to match springSecurityFilterChain, I've been pulling my hair for a few hours now because of this. But seems this is how the spring guys have coded it http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started