# Spring MVC: IP restriction for a single controller method

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to hide a specific API for requests coming form IP different to a specific one.
For instance this should work if I try to use it and my IP is 192.168.1.1, but not if my IP is 192.168.1.2.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@IpRestricted
public void download(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
  ...
}
```

I read I can make it creating a specific annotation, the one I called "@IpRestricted" in this example, but than how can I proceed? There are better solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I then realized I can make it without using spring security.
I made an annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IpRestricted {
}
```

Than I check the request IP address inside a HandlerInterceptor preHandle method:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod)handler;
        if (method.getMethodAnnotation(IpRestricted.class)!=null) {
            if (!request.getRemoteAddr().equals("192.168.1.1")) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException("Ip not authorized");
            }
        }
    }
    [....]
}
```

And for the download method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@IpRestricted
public void download(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
   ...
}
```

That's it!

Comment: What are these two checks for? `if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod)` and `if (method.getMethodAnnotation(IpRestricted.class)!=null)`? What are the cases in which these checks will be `false`?

Comment: First tells you if the Object is going to be the method handling your request. Second can be null if the annotation IpRestrictred is not present among "download()" method annotations. For example if you don't want all methods are restricted by ip you will configure the annotation only on methods requiring it.

Comment: Thanks! And what else can there be instead of `HandlerMethod`in `if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod)`?

Comment: For example it can be a org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler

Answer (score 0):

I think the best Spring solution available for this case is the `hasIpAddress()` method from **Spring Security**. There are many different ways to configure permissions to your services via Spring Security, and the IP-based solution is also implemented.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-access-control-example/) is a good example of how to set it up.

Comment: in spring security I saw I can use also <intercept-url pattern="/someURL/*" access="hasIpAddress('192.168.1.1')" /> but i stil cannot understand where I should put it...

Comment: You have two options. Either you use Annotations (example: @PreAuthorize("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')"), or put together a "security.xml" config file.

Comment: I imported the spring security dependency and added to the controller method the annotation @PreAuthorize but it seems it's not working

Comment: it's simply ignoring the PreAuthorize annotation, neither gives a different result nor error.

Comment: Well, the most common reason of Spring Security not working I think is the filter not being registered at all. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10427242/821786 .

Comment: Thanks a lot i thik it should work now but i found a solution without using the spring security, what do you thing about it? can it be ok?

Comment: It will work, yes. Spring security is a flexible library, but being a library it is obviously more complex. If you are not planning to do further improvements on your authentication in this app, then it is completely ok to use the homemade annotation.